# What does "on" mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, prepositions

I was reading something and there was this sentence.

> On receiving a
> letter from Bogle, Lady Tichborne sent enough money to pay for the fare back to England.

What does on mean in this sentence?

Comment: The relevant definition is [**used as a function word to indicate a time frame during which something takes place,  or an instant, action, or occurrence when something begins or is done on cue**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/on).  But **on** has so many definitions it would be hard to pick the right one if you didn't already know!

Answer (score 2):

It means 'when she received the letter'. Presumably Lady T. sent the money in response to a request in the letter.